# Find all permutation sequences with only neighbor swaps

Tags: permutations, hamiltonian-path, cayley-graphs

I am trying to essentially do what was done at this [link](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~holroyd/minimus.html), except for five elements instead of four.

The link gives all of the possible sequences of permutations of four elements with the following 2 constraints:

1. Only neighbor swaps are allowed to get the next permutation in the sequence
2. The sequence has to end on the same permutation it started on - it's a cycle

I'm trying to solve the same problem with 5 elements, find all sequences of 120 swaps that visit every permutation. There are 7 valid swaps for each row:

12345

Ｘ|||

ＸＸ|

Ｘ|Ｘ

|Ｘ||

|ＸＸ

||Ｘ|

|||Ｘ

I can only think to make a graph and find all the Hamiltonian cycles on it, and I don't know how to do that without making it take til the sun burns out. Is there a way to solve this in a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: Are you trying to sequence through all 120 permutations of five elements?

Comment: Yes. An example of the kind of valid sequence I'm looking for is produced by the steinhaus johnson trotter algorithm, where each permutation is arrived at by a series of single swaps. However, sequences with two swaps in the same row are also valid, for example swapping position 1 with position 2 and swapping position 3 with position 4 at the same time.

Comment: I think finding all sequences is fairly ambitious. Even counting them looks far from obvious.

Comment: I don't know enough about the subject to say what's possible, but I think there should be a way to do it that's computationally feasible. I just don't know enough about the subject to answer it.

Comment: I agree that it would be fairly easy to write a short program to count the number of ways for $n=5$, or even to print them all out.

Comment: If you are to swap the neighbouring pair one at a time you can make 4 distinct swaps. Make four swaps test each one and put it on a stack if it has not occurred before. Do the same with each element of stack recursively.

Comment: 1) I stated in the problem there are 7 swaps that can be done, since multiple swaps per row are allowed, and 2) Your solution has me checking 1.7668*10^72 different combinations. That's rather unfeasible.